# Conflicting jQuery with core Joomla scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

This two jQuery codes are conflicting with each other and i'm at lost as to how to go about it. I have tried many noConflict combinations to the first part of the script.

```
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
        $('.slider').sss();
        });
    </script>
```

Conflicting with this core joomla code that i don't want to change for various reasons. So any change must be done to the script mentioned above

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).on('load',  function() {
                new JCaption('img.caption');
            });
    </script>
```

Any thoughts on how to go about modifying the first script?

Comment: try using [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)...

Comment: That's the first thing i did. It didn't work.

Comment: did you use it correctly?

Comment: yes i did. Anyways, i resolved the issue by overwriting the core. Found a script which was 2012 old and simply changed a few variables.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the core by overwriting it:

```
    if (isset($this->_script['text/javascript']))
    {
        $this->_script['text/javascript'] = preg_replace('%jQuery\(\window\)\.on\(\'load\',\s*function\(\)\s*{\s*new\s*JCaption\(\'img.caption\'\);\s*}\);\s*%', '', $this->_script['text/javascript']);
        if (empty($this->_script['text/javascript']))
            unset($this->_script['text/javascript']);
    }
```